# Connector allowing charger and usb computer connection as same time?

Tags: usb, charging

[PoE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet) lead me to idea of having some kind connector, allowing supplying my connected tabled with power from it's charger (5V 2A) and in same time being connected to computer (for backup or whatever purpose).

Do you know such hardware solution?

To make it bold: I want to connect charger for power (2A) and have data connection in same time! (imagine a kind of "Y" saped thing :) )

Comment: I don't understand your issue: connecting your Android device via USB does exactly that (except for the 2A, maybe), it charges your device while connected to the computer. And yes, while charging this way, data connections are possible. I use that regularly this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use one of [these](http://www.startech.com/m/Cards-Adapters/USB-3.0/Hubs/6-Port-USB-3-USB-Combo-Hub-with-2A-Charging-Port-2x-USB-3-4x-USB-2~ST7320USBC) which has one 2.1A USB port, but only if the device you are charging supports it. Most devices when transferring data lock the power output to the standard USB power standard when connected as a data device though.

Also if you are using a modded device with a USB fast charge enabled kernel, you won't be able to accomplish what you want because of how it is implemented. The force USB fast charge mode tricks the phone into thinking it is on mains power so it shuts off data ports.

Answer (score 1):

It works that way by default. You can plug into your computer and use data while charging.  It may be your specific USB cable, I have seen some that don't always work. Bottom line there is nothing special needed

Comment: No it doesn't. I can not connect charger for power (2A) and have data connection in same time!

Comment: @Booger USB ports can't supply 2A or power, only 100/500/900mA for USB 1/2/3 respectively.

Comment: I am just saying that this is a limitation to your hardware (Computer, Cable, or device) - as by default you can charge and use data at same time.